# How to keep mesh exactly as it was after a simple modifier when I join it up with another object

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm a newbie to blender so sorry if this is a simple question.

I took a cylinder and 2 half spheres joined them and then bridged edge loops. I need something that is thinner in the middle so then I used an add modify / stretch which gave me the form I desired in the middle part, but squished the spherical caps. I removed them and I'm trying to attach new half-spherical surfaces back. The problem is that the moment I join them the stretch is re-applied again and destroys both the spherical cap and the middle part.

How can I make the modifier not re-apply after join? Thanks.

PS I cant upload a picture for some reason :(

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! A possible hack (if I correctly undersand your problem) could be to duplicate the object, apply the modifier on one of them, remove the unwanted part from both, join and sew. For a complete and answer, I think you should be able to post a pic, a testfile or describe the situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an image it's hard to guess which form you exactly want to achieve, but if you would like to make the cylindrical part thinner I would add some loop cuts and shrink them to your liking.[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That would also be a solution I tried it but it does not give me a smooth curving transition like the simple deform. But I will use this. Thanks again.

I would love to upload an image I click the image I select the file and the only option it gives me is cancel. It's 500kB so it's small I tried jpeg and png. I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: It all depends on what you are modeling for. If it's a low poly model for a RT game engine you want to stick with a low poly count. If you want to use it for images/animation you could still add a multiresolution or subdivision surface modifier. In both cases your result should be smoothed out.